# Spring mvc 3.1 integration tests with session support

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc

I'm using the new [spring-test](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/) in the 3.1 version to run integration tests. It works really well but I can't make the session to work. My code:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("src/main/webapp")
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext-dataSource.xml",
      "classpath:applicationContext.xml",
      "classpath:applicationContext-security-roles.xml",
      "classpath:applicationContext-security-web.xml",
      "classpath:applicationContext-web.xml"})
public class SpringTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected MockMvc mock;
    protected MockHttpSession mockSession;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       initDataSources("dataSource.properties");

       mock = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
       mockSession = new MockHttpSession(wac.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {
        // this controller sets a variable in the session
        mock.perform(get("/")
            .session(mockSession))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("csrf"));

        // I set another variable here just to be sure
        mockSession.setAttribute(CSRFHandlerInterceptor.CSRF, csrf);

        // this call returns 403 instead of 200 because the session is empty...
        mock.perform(post("/setup/language")
            .session(mockSession)
            .param(CSRFHandlerInterceptor.CSRF, csrf)
            .param("language", "de"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

My session is empty in every request, I don't know why.

**EDIT:** The last assert is failing: `andExpect(status().isOk());`. It returns 403 instead of 200.

Comment: Which assertion is failing?

Comment: The last one: `andExpect(status().isOk());` because i check the session for a variable that should be set, but the session is empty so it returns forbidden.

Comment: See also [How to login a user with spring 3.2 new mvc testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308341/how-to-login-a-user-with-spring-3-2-new-mvc-testing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done this in a somewhat roundabout manner - works though. What I did was to let Spring-Security create a session with the relevant Security attributes populated in the session and then grab that session this way:

```
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/j_spring_security_check")
            .param("j_username", "fred")
            .param("j_password", "fredspassword"))
            .andExpect(status().isMovedTemporarily())
            .andDo(new ResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
                    sessionHolder.setSession(new SessionWrapper(result.getRequest().getSession()));
                }
            });
```

SessionHolder is my custom class, just to hold the session:

```
private static final class SessionHolder{
    private SessionWrapper session;


    public SessionWrapper getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(SessionWrapper session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

and SessionWrapper is another class extending from MockHttpSession, just because the session method requires MockHttpSession:

```
private static class SessionWrapper extends MockHttpSession{
    private final HttpSession httpSession;

    public SessionWrapper(HttpSession httpSession){
        this.httpSession = httpSession;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(String name) {
        return this.httpSession.getAttribute(name);
    }

}
```

With these set, now you can simply take the session from the sessionHolder and execute subsequent methods, for eg. in my case:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/membersjson/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).session(sessionHolder.getSession()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("OneUpdated")));
```

Answer (score 27):

UPDATED ANSWER:

It seems a new method "sessionAttrs" has been added to the builder (see [mvc controller test with session attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341400/mvc-controller-test-with-session-attribute/26341909#26341909))

```
Map<String, Object> sessionAttrs = new HashMap<>();
sessionAttrs.put("sessionAttrName", "sessionAttrValue");

mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/uri").sessionAttrs(sessionAttrs))
      .andDo(print())
      .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

OLD ANSWER:

here is a simpler solution to achieve the same result without using supporting classes, this is a snippet of my code (I don't know if these methods had been already available when Biju Kunjummen answered):

```
        HttpSession session = mockMvc.perform(post("/login-process").param("j_username", "user1").param("j_password", "user1"))
            .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.FOUND.value()))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/"))
            .andReturn()
            .getRequest()
            .getSession();              

        Assert.assertNotNull(session);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/").session((MockHttpSession)session).locale(Locale.ENGLISH))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk()) 
            .andExpect(view().name("logged_in"));
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer! Current accepted answer is a very dirty hack to achieve this.

Comment: I'm having a problem implementing this solution. Im getting the following exception `NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`. Any idea what could be causing it?