# How to login a user with spring 3.2 new mvc testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

This works fine until I have to test a service that needs a logged in user, how do I add user to context :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext-test.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FooTest {
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Resource(name = "aService")
private AService aService; //uses logged in user

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
}
```

Comment: See also [Spring mvc 3.1 integration tests with session support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687055/spring-mvc-3-1-integration-tests-with-session-support).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to use MockMVC with the latest spring security test package, try this code:

```
Principal principal = new Principal() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "TEST_PRINCIPAL";
        }
    };
getMockMvc().perform(get("http://your-url.com").principal(principal))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()));
```

Keep in mind that you have to be using Principal based authentication for this to work.

Comment: Another possibilty is to use com.sun.security.auth.UserPrincipal:

`getMockMvc().perform(get("http://your-url.com").principal(new UserPrincipal("TEST_USER_ID"))).andExpect(status().isOk()));`

Answer (score 12):

If successful authentication yields some cookie, then you can capture that (or just all cookies), and pass it along in the next tests:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy filterChain;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
      .addFilter(filterChain).build();
}

@Test
public void testSession() throws Exception {
    // Login and save the cookie
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/session")
      .param("username", "john").param("password", "s3cr3t")).andReturn();
    Cookie c = result.getResponse().getCookie("my-cookie");
    assertThat(c.getValue().length(), greaterThan(10));

    // No cookie; 401 Unauthorized
    mockMvc.perform(get("/personal").andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());

    // With cookie; 200 OK
    mockMvc.perform(get("/personal").cookie(c)).andExpect(status().isOk());

    // Logout, and ensure we're told to wipe the cookie
    result = mockMvc.perform(delete("/session").andReturn();
    c = result.getResponse().getCookie("my-cookie");
    assertThat(c.getValue().length(), is(0));
}
```

Though I know I'm not making any HTTP requests here, I kind of like the stricter separation of the above integration test and my controllers and Spring Security implementation.

To make the code a bit less verbose, I use the following to merge the cookies after making each request, and then pass those cookies along in each subsequent request:

```
/**
 * Merges the (optional) existing array of Cookies with the response in the
 * given MockMvc ResultActions.
 * <p>
 * This only adds or deletes cookies. Officially, we should expire old
 * cookies. But we don't keep track of when they were created, and this is
 * not currently required in our tests.
 */
protected static Cookie[] updateCookies(final Cookie[] current,
  final ResultActions result) {

    final Map<String, Cookie> currentCookies = new HashMap<>();
    if (current != null) {
        for (Cookie c : current) {
            currentCookies.put(c.getName(), c);
        }
    }

    final Cookie[] newCookies = result.andReturn().getResponse().getCookies();
    for (Cookie newCookie : newCookies) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(newCookie.getValue())) {
            // An empty value implies we're told to delete the cookie
            currentCookies.remove(newCookie.getName());
        } else {
            // Add, or replace:
            currentCookies.put(newCookie.getName(), newCookie);
        }
    }

    return currentCookies.values().toArray(new Cookie[currentCookies.size()]);
}
```

...and a small helper as `cookie(...)` needs at least one cookie:

```
/**
 * Creates an array with a dummy cookie, useful as Spring MockMvc
 * {@code cookie(...)} does not like {@code null} values or empty arrays.
 */
protected static Cookie[] initCookies() {
    return new Cookie[] { new Cookie("unittest-dummy", "dummy") };
}
```

...to end up with:

```
Cookie[] cookies = initCookies();

ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/personal").cookie(cookies)
  .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
cookies = updateCookies(cookies, actions);

actions = mockMvc.perform(post("/session").cookie(cookies)
  .param("username", "john").param("password", "s3cr3t"));
cookies = updateCookies(cookies, actions);

actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/personal").cookie(cookies))
  .andExpect(status().isOk());
cookies = updateCookies(cookies, actions);
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I'll try anyways: I wanted to get the cookies on the exact same way, but somehow, my response().getCookies() returns an empty array. Yet I'm one hundret percent sure, that the request returns a cookie.

Comment: Are you using `andReturn()`? Then I've no idea, sorry.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just add the user to the security context:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
list.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));        
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password,list);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Comment: yeah thanks this fixes it, I wondered if there was a new way for spring 3.2 and mockMvc

Answer (score 2):

Somewhy solution with principal didn't worked for me, thus, I'd like to mention another way out:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("your/url/{id}", 5).with(user("anyUserName")))
```

Comment: import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;

Answer (score 2):

With spring 4 this solution mock the formLogin and logout using sessions and not cookies because spring security test not returning cookies.

Because it's not a best practice to inherit tests you can @Autowire this component in your tests and call it's methods.

With this solution each perform operation on the `mockMvc` will be called as authenticated if you called the `performLogin` on the end of the test you can call `performLogout`.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import static com.condix.SessionLogoutRequestBuilder.sessionLogout;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestBuilders.formLogin;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.authenticated;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.unauthenticated;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@Component
public class SessionBasedMockMvc {

    private static final String HOME_PATH = "/";
    private static final String LOGOUT_PATH = "/login?logout";

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    public MockMvc createSessionBasedMockMvc() {
        final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder defaultRequestBuilder = get("/dummy-path");
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
                .defaultRequest(defaultRequestBuilder)
                .alwaysDo(result -> setSessionBackOnRequestBuilder(defaultRequestBuilder, result.getRequest()))
                .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .build();
        return this.mockMvc;
    }

    public void performLogin(final String username, final String password) throws Exception {
        final ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user(username).password(password));
        this.assertSuccessLogin(resultActions);
    }

    public void performLogout() throws Exception {
        final ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc.perform(sessionLogout());
        this.assertSuccessLogout(resultActions);
    }

    private MockHttpServletRequest setSessionBackOnRequestBuilder(final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder,
                                                                  final MockHttpServletRequest request) {
        requestBuilder.session((MockHttpSession) request.getSession());
        return request;
    }

    private void assertSuccessLogin(final ResultActions resultActions) throws Exception {
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isFound())
                .andExpect(authenticated())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl(HOME_PATH));
    }

    private void assertSuccessLogout(final ResultActions resultActions) throws Exception {
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isFound())
                .andExpect(unauthenticated())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl(LOGOUT_PATH));
    }

}
```

Because default `LogoutRequestBuilder` doesn't support session we need to create another logout request builder.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.Mergeable;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.ConfigurableSmartRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.RequestPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

/**
 * This is a logout request builder which allows to send the session on the request.<br/>
 * It also has more than one post processors.<br/>
 * <br/>
 * Unfortunately it won't trigger {@link org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionDestroyedEvent} because
 * that is triggered by {@link org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade#invalidate()} in Tomcat and
 * for mocks it's handled by @{{@link MockHttpSession#invalidate()}} so the log out message won't be visible for tests.
 */
public final class SessionLogoutRequestBuilder implements
        ConfigurableSmartRequestBuilder<SessionLogoutRequestBuilder>, Mergeable {

    private final List<RequestPostProcessor> postProcessors = new ArrayList<>();
    private String logoutUrl = "/logout";
    private MockHttpSession session;

    private SessionLogoutRequestBuilder() {
        this.postProcessors.add(csrf());
    }

    static SessionLogoutRequestBuilder sessionLogout() {
        return new SessionLogoutRequestBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public MockHttpServletRequest buildRequest(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        return post(this.logoutUrl).session(session).buildRequest(servletContext);
    }

    public SessionLogoutRequestBuilder logoutUrl(final String logoutUrl) {
        this.logoutUrl = logoutUrl;
        return this;
    }

    public SessionLogoutRequestBuilder session(final MockHttpSession session) {
        Assert.notNull(session, "'session' must not be null");
        this.session = session;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMergeEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object merge(final Object parent) {
        if (parent == null) {
            return this;
        }

        if (parent instanceof MockHttpServletRequestBuilder) {
            final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder parentBuilder = (MockHttpServletRequestBuilder) parent;
            if (this.session == null) {
                this.session = (MockHttpSession) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(parentBuilder, "session");
            }
            final List postProcessors = (List) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(parentBuilder, "postProcessors");
            this.postProcessors.addAll(0, (List<RequestPostProcessor>) postProcessors);
        } else if (parent instanceof SessionLogoutRequestBuilder) {
            final SessionLogoutRequestBuilder parentBuilder = (SessionLogoutRequestBuilder) parent;
            if (!StringUtils.hasText(this.logoutUrl)) {
                this.logoutUrl = parentBuilder.logoutUrl;
            }
            if (this.session == null) {
                this.session = parentBuilder.session;
            }
            this.postProcessors.addAll(0, parentBuilder.postProcessors);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot merge with [" + parent.getClass().getName() + "]");
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public SessionLogoutRequestBuilder with(final RequestPostProcessor postProcessor) {
        Assert.notNull(postProcessor, "postProcessor is required");
        this.postProcessors.add(postProcessor);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
        for (final RequestPostProcessor postProcessor : this.postProcessors) {
            request = postProcessor.postProcessRequest(request);
            if (request == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Post-processor [" + postProcessor.getClass().getName() + "] returned null");
            }
        }
        return request;
    }

}
```

After calling the `performLogin` operation all your request in the test will be automatically performed as logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way... I use the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    WithSecurityContextTestExcecutionListener.class})
@WithMockUser
public class WithMockUserTests {
    ...
}
```

[(source)](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/07/preview-spring-security-test-method-security#security-test-setup)