# Spring MVC testing (security Integration test), JSESSIONID is not present

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, mockmvc, spring-mvc-test

I have created custom login form for my spring boot app.
In my form integration test, I want to check that received cookies contain **JSESSIONID** and **XSRF-TOKEN**.

But, I received only **XSRF-TOKEN**.

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class UserIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private Integer port;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc =
                MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
                        .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserInfoTest() throws Exception {
        disableSslVerification();

        MvcResult result =
                mockMvc.perform(formLogin("/login").user("roy").password("spring")).andExpect(authenticated())
                        .andReturn();
        Cookie sessionId = result.getResponse().getCookie("JSESSIONID");
        Cookie token = result.getResponse().getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
}
```

Security conf:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http
            //.httpBasic()
            //.and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority(Authority.Type.ROLE_ADMIN.getName())
                .antMatchers("/login**", "/index.html", "/home.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login.jsp")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                     .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsp").permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Please, help me to obtain the required result.

Answer (score 4):

You also don't see Set-Cookie header. For me it's a big limitation of MockMVC. For a workaround see [Why does Spring MockMvc result not contain a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281932/926620).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring security with default login endpoint, there is a good news.
you dont need JSESSION from cookies after invoking /login ep. just use @WithMockUser
above your test method, perform login request and from now, all your requests will be authorized as the last logged user.