# Testing session invalidation in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am playing around with Spring Security and now I am trying get some knowledge about testing my REST-controller with regards to security.

So I prepared my test-class with:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

containing test-cases mostly of the following or similar form:

```
@Test
public void handleSecuredRequest_shouldReturn200_withAdminUser() throws Exception{
    ResultActions action = mvc.perform(get("/secured").with(user("admin").roles("ADMIN")));

    int status = action.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus();
    assertTrue("expected status code = 200 ; current status code = " + status, status == 200);
}
```

What I was not able to achieve until now were things concerning sessions.
Most notably I would be interested to verify that session-invalidation is performed correctly.

How can I achieve that?

---

**EDIT:**

I was able to find something close to a solution doing the following based on 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281932/6294605 :

```
@Test
public void logout_shouldInvalidateSession_withLoggedInUser() throws Exception{
    ResultActions action = mvc.perform(get("/userAsJSON").with(user("user")));
    MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession) action.andReturn().getRequest().getSession();

    ResultActions action2 = mvc.perform(post("/logout").session(session));

    ResultActions action3 = mvc.perform(get("/userAsJSON").session(session));
    int status3 = action3.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus();

    assertTrue("expected status code = 401 ; current status code = " + status3, status3 == 401);
}
```

But I am not entirely satisfied with this.

1. It requires to process several steps to let me test what I want.
2. Resulting from 1.: it is not detached from certain other things to function correctly (e.g. the "/userAsJSON" endpoint returning 401 for not authenticated users).
3. Resulting from 2.: it requires additional attention to make sure that test-cases exist that ensure that the formal requirements for my test to be valid are met.

So I would wish for an option to make this less error-prone.

Any ideas?