# Spring integration testing of logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Controller that contains a logout endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/logout")
public ResponseEntity<Void> logout() {
    var request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    try {
        request.logout();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        log.error("Unable to logout");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

How can I test this using mockmvc ?

What I have so far is this piece of code, but I don't know how to test that the request.logout() was called (what are its effects?).

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/logout").principal(principal)).expect(??)
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308341/how-to-login-a-user-with-spring-3-2-new-mvc-testing/47069613):

Using spring security test package, try this code:

```
getMockMvc().perform(get("http://login.com").principal(principal))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()));
```

Or:

```
getMockMvc().perform(get("http://your-url.com").principal(new UserPrincipal("TEST_USER_ID"))).andExpect(status().isOk()));
```

Comment: Well the part I'm interested in testing is not really the status code but the side effect that is produced by `request.logout()`. In other words, I would want the test to fail if I comment out `request.logout()`. Your snippet doesn't achieve that.

Comment: Ok take a look at the post I montioned in the solution, you can use this `final ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc.perform(sessionLogout());` from @Nagy Attila solution

Comment: I'm not sure how it relates, can you please edit your answer then ?