# mvc controller test with session attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, attributes, junit4, httpsession

I'm trying to test a method with this signature:

```
 @Autowired
HttpSession http_Session;
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/search/findByName")
public @ResponseBody List<Map> search(@RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name){
Integer user_id = http_Session.getAttribute("userinfo");
}
```

userinfo is a class which contains informations about the user and set in session scope when the user logged in.but when I try the test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration 
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
   "classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext.xml"})

 public class userControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;  
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before 
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
 }  
 @Test
 public void userTest() throws Exception {
     mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/search/findByName").param("name", "bob"))
          .andDo(print())
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
```

The problem is the userinfo class attribute is set in another method so when i try to access it in this method  i got a NullPointerException , and with Autowiring the httpSession i got a new Session for each method   i have to test.

What should i do with the session attribute, my method doesn't accept a session parameter , and for each test it create a WebApplicationContext with a new session.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this :

```
HashMap<String, Object> sessionattr = new HashMap<String, Object>();
sessionattr.put("userinfo", "XXXXXXXX");

mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/search/findByName").sessionAttrs(sessionattr).param("name", "bob"))
          .andDo(print())
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also share a session across different requests:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.SharedHttpSessionConfigurer.sharedHttpSession;

@Before 
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
    .webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
    .apply(sharedHttpSession()) // use this session across requests
    .build();
}
```

note: this session will be shared among requests performed against the same `MockMvc` instance only.

Comment: This worked after I autowired the application context ```@Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;``` in my ```@SpringBootTest``` test class.